# Custom graphic in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a WPF application which has a picture box with a graphic in it, I need a way to be able to change this graphic in a simple straightforward manner (like replacing an image file in the programs install directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that loads an image from an external image file

```
public static ImageSource LoadImage(string fileName)
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("file:///" + fileName.Replace("\\", "/"));
    bitmap.EndInit();
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can then assign an image controls source to this functions return value.

```
someImageControl.Source = LoadImage(@"d:\\images\\image.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but...

You could do something like this:

```
Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/someimage.png"
```

and use images off of your bin/app folder. Take a look at this link for more info...

[What is application's site of origin and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043138/what-is-applications-site-of-origin-and-when-to-use-it)