# C# WPF Load images from the exe folder

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, load

i want to move my program from a pc to another but the problem is the images are not loaded on any other pc (Source problem) . So i was wondering if i could just create a folder where the exe is placed and name it Resources and to load every image from there.

```
image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Res\startoh.png"));
```

Comment: The above code does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may just add the images as resources to your Visual Studio project. Then they will be packed into the assembly of the executable and you don't need to copy them separately.

Create a folder in your project (let's say called **Images**) and add your images to that folder.

[image]

Make sure that the [Build Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145769/1136211) for the images is set to `Resource`.

[image]

Now you can simply create a BitmapImage from such a resource by an appropriate [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/SomeImage.png");
image.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/someimage.png"
```

and use images off of your bin/app folder. Take a look at this link for more info...

[Custom graphic in WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636502/custom-graphic-in-wpf-application)

[What is application's site of origin and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043138/what-is-applications-site-of-origin-and-when-to-use-it)

Comment: This answers the question of how to load an image in the 'exe' folder by using 'siteoforigin'. Thanks, this saved me!