# XAML Parse Exception on set image source on button

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my `XAML` code

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,0,0,0" Width="20" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ToolTip="Search" Foreground="#FFB9B9B9">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="../Images/gray-classic-search-icon.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

This is giving me this error on run project:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '34' and line position '33'.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an image from a relative path is not an ideal approach in a WPF application, because at runtime the image file needs to reside in exactly the right relative location, be it `..\Images\` or `..\..\Images\`.

You should instead set the Build Action of the image file to `Resource` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16075863/1136211)) and load it like this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/gray-classic-search-icon.png" .../>
```

which is the short form of a [WPF Resource File Pack Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/gray-classic-search-icon.png" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,0,0,0" Width="20" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ToolTip="Search" Foreground="#FFB9B9B9">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="../../Images/gray-classic-search-icon.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```