# how to get application path in resources tag in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Iam developing an application where i need to read data from an xml file and need to show the data in a combobox. I have followed the example from net and completed the application.
But now i need the path of the file from a the bin or from the application startup.

```
   <Grid.Resources>
        <!--<Path> string currpath ="System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory"</Path>-->
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="AppConfig" **Source="Z:\\AppConfiguration.xml"** XPath="Configuration"/>

    </Grid.Resources>
```

Now i want Source from the application path where the file will be stored.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you bind the path in code?

Answer (score 0):

first define one property for storing xmlfilepath value

```
public string xmlfilepath{get;set;}
```

you can get application base directory in code behind and store in it one variable and make concated string of path like this

```
xmlfilepath= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "your folder name and file name path will come here";
```

and then you can bind Source property with path variable  like below

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="AppConfig" Source="{Binding xmlfilepath,Mode=Twoway,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" XPath="Configuration"/>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. i have tried the code you gave but its giving an error Error 1 A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'XmlDataProvider'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: @AshokRathod He just stated that it does not work.. Why should he then mark it as an answer?

Comment: in that case i would suggest u direclty bind xml file to your required control like done in below stated example   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866942/how-to-bind-xmldataprovider-source-to-mvvm-property

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pack://siteoforigin:` or `pack://application:`. For example:

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Logo.png" />
```

Comment: Those two are not the same :) See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043138/what-is-applications-site-of-origin-and-when-to-use-it