# WPF UserControl Runtime error: Unable to find path of the icon in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In my `WPF User Control`, I have added an icon (shown in the XAML below). But at run time, the `InitializeComponent()` call in the following code of the user control gives the error shown below:

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
…………….
}
```

**XAML of the User Control** (with icon):

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
            "d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Icon="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/test_32.png">
    <Grid>
………………
    </Grid>
```

**Error**:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\MyFolder\VSTO\MyProject\bin\Debug\Resources\MyIcon.png'.

**Remark**:

I noticed that `Resources` folder does not get created under `Debug` folder although it is part of the project. I have set MyIcon.png file with `Build` action as `Resource` and `Copy to output directory` is set to `Copy if newer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't why but you should use `application` with resources Uri and `siteoforigin` with the rest.

You can either change your Uri to:

```
Icon="pack://application:,,,/Resources/test_32.png"
```

Or if you want to keep using `siteoforigin` than change the build option to "content" instead of "Resource".
Related topics:

[What is application's site of origin and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043239/5228202)

[pack-uris-in-wpf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#The_siteoforigin_____Authority)

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I changed the build action to `content`. Also, your references were of great help (it's a good practices so others can get help, as well)